# Анимированный круг на карте (Google Maps JavaScript API V3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Как, допустим, при добавлении маркера добавить вокруг него такой анимированный круг?

[image: Пример анимированного круга]

Answer (score 2):

Добавляет, круг к городу, по числености населения

```
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: citymap[city].center,
            radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
          });
```